# Hiding/Showing a column on toggling a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## Hiding a column on unchecking a checkbox

**NOTE: Before you point to links based on the same question, I need to tell I tried all the relevant solutions here and nothing worked. I signed up precisely coz none of the solutions here actually worked.**

So, my code lets you create a table dynamically and edit the table contents as well. For every new column created,a checkbox is also added which when unselected hides the created column.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"             src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function addrow()
{    
 first_row = $('#Row1');
 first_row.clone().appendTo('random');
}
function addcol()
{
 var myform = $('#myform'),
 iter = 1;
 myform.find('tr').each(function(){
           var trow = $(this);
             if(trow.index() === 0){
                 trow.append('<th contenteditable="true" class="COLUMN_'+iter+'"><b>COLUMN # '+iter+'</b></td>');
                  var labelname = "Show COLUMN #" +iter;
            var create = $('<input type="checkbox" name="COLUMN_'+iter+'"     checked="checked"><label>'+labelname+'</label><br>');
           $(".noprint").append(create);
             }else{
                 trow.append('<td class="COLUMN_'+iter+'" contenteditable="true"></td>');
             }
         });
         iter += 1;       
}
$(window).load(function(){
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var column = "."+$(this).attr("name");
    $(column).toggle();
});
});
</script>  
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Add new row"     onclick="addrow()"/>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;<input type="button" value="Add new column"     onclick="addcol()"/>
<br>
<br>
 <span class="noprint"> </span>
<form id="myform">
<table id="random" width="70%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name 1</th>
    <th>Name 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Row1">
    <td contenteditable="true">Entry 1</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">Entry 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">Entry 3</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">Entry 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm unable to hide the columns based on the checkbox status. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: CSS could do this : hide/show row or colums via class or id if it's about a single col or row.  Demo with checbox and radio to show it can be made https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/HBjDn include the selector to the rule while adding the row

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
$(“#myform”).on(“click”,”input[type=‘checkbox’]”,function(){
    var column = "."+$(this).attr("name");
    $(column).toggle();
});
```

Since your checkbox elements are added later, you need to listen for the click event on the parent element and then bind to the child.